# Putting a Flask app with gunicorn behind Caddy reverse proxy

Tags: flask, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, caddy

I have a Flask app which I am running with gunicorn. It works by itself. I can reach the app at `localhost/` and go to other links from there. The app assumes its root path is `/` and generates all relative URLs accordingly.

Now I want to put this behind a reverse proxy, for which I use Caddy. But also I want it to be on a subpath. So users would see `example.com/myapp/` as the root page, and pages like `example.com/myapp/profile`. However, the Flask app's code would continue to have things like `<a href="/profile">`. I assume Caddy can simply rewrite the URLs and make it all work, since other servers I've used have all been able to work this way, although they usually take some kind of "root URL" config parameter.

However, when I run my app with the reverse proxy, the URLs are broken. It tries to send users from `example.com/myapp/` to `example.com/profile` instead of `example.com/myapp/profile`. My Caddyfile currently just says:

```
handle_path /myapp/* {
    reverse_proxy internal.app.url:8000
}
```

How can I get the links to work correctly? Is this a problem that should be solved in the Caddyfile, the gunicorn configuration, or my Flask app?

Gunicorn has an example nginx config where they set some proxy headers: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html However, in my experience nginx has some silly defaults and configuration ends up being verbose because of it. How much of this stuff would I need to replicate in my Caddyfile, and how?

Flask apparently has a `url_for` method which can dynamically generate URLs. However, I could simply define a `ROOT_URL` parameter in my app, and prepend that to all my relative URLs. I'm pretty sure it would work, but it would make all the URLs look ugly, and I couldn't access my app's pages at `localhost/profile` anymore (for testing), I would have to use `localhost/myapp/profile`. Also the "recommended" `url_for` seems more work than just doing it myself, so I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I believe the problem is in the `Caddyfile`. You should use `handle` instead of `handle_path` to not strip the prefix from the url.

From the Caddy documentation for `handle_path`:

> Works the same as the `handle` directive, but implicitly uses `uri strip_prefix` to strip the matched path prefix.